# What does this kernel code mean?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I found this in an old kernel code :

```
#define hlist_for_each_entry(tpos, pos, head, member)                    \
        for (pos = (head)->first;                                        \
             pos &&                                                      \
                ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
             pos = pos->next)
```

but I don't understand how I should interpret the meaning of this line:

```
({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;});
```

How does the compiler undersand the meaning of more than one expression inside braces/parentheses (the `({...;...;})` construct)?

Comment: It seems there is used a language extension of the compiler that allows to use compound statements like expressions.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this construction

```
({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;});
```

is based on its own language extension of the compiler and allows to use compound statements in expressions. It is similar to lambda expressions in C++.

I think that the result of evaluation of the construction has value 1.

In my opinion it is simply a bad code because the same can be written using the comma operator like

```
pos && ( ( tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member) ), 1 ); \
             pos = pos->next)
```

Comment: It is a gcc extension, documented here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Answer (score 2):

It's a GCC language extension, "braced-groups" within expressions.
As @nos said in a comment on the other answer, the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) explains it.
The expression `(EXP1; EXP2; ...; EXPn;)` has he value of `EXPn`.
You're supposed to use the others for their side effects -- see this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int b;
    printf("%d\n", ({ b=3; 2;}) );  
    printf("%d\n",b);
    exit(0);
}
```

If you compile this with GCC without any compile options, for example, it will print 2, and then 3.

But compiling with `-Wall -pedantic` forces GCC to strictly follow the standard, rejecting anything that the standard dowsn't allow. It will tell us that this extension is not allowed:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5:17: warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
  printf("%d\n", ({ b=3; 2;}) ); 
                 ^
```